# Python replacing multiple words in a function with a loop?

Tags: python

How do I replace a word with another word using a `loop`. For example, let's say I have a `function` called "`changeWords`" and I want this function to change three words *can't*, *shouldn't*, *don't* to *cannot*, *should not*, *do not*. So when the function is entered, '`changeWords("I don't know how to do this")'` should return back "`I do not know how to do this".`

To clarify:

```
changeWords(“I can't eat") -> “I can not eat"
changeWords(“I don't like swimming.”) -> “I do not like swimming.”
changeWords(“I shouldn't do that.”) -> “I should not do that.”
```

My attempt:

```
def stringChange(a):
a = ""
for line in stringChange("a"):
    line = text.replace("a","can't","can not")
    if not line: break
    return line
```

Comment: fix your formatting and clearify what you really want to do.

Comment: Your sample doesn't compile and (if you fix the indentation) contains an infinite recursion. It also doesn't contain a function called `changeWords`.

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216636/multiple-word-replace-in-text-python) out.. It does the multi word replace you are looking for.

Comment: "I can't" doesn't mean the same thing as "I can not". Your replacement is wrong. [Why is “cannot” spelled as one word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4510/why-is-cannot-spelled-as-one-word)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> def changeWords(s):
        for old, new in (
                ("can't", "can not"),
                ("shouldn't", "should not"),
                ("don't", "do not"),
            ):    
            s = s.replace(old, new)
        return s

>>> changeWords("I don't know how to do this")
'I do not know how to do this'
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. I have one question why do you have a one parenthesis on the second line "r new in (" also you have another in line 6 " ):" ?

Comment: Those two parens delimit the outer tuple.  Without them, you would need a backslash line continuation character on each of the tuples in the for-loop.